# Return outside function error in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to do some automated web scraping as my first project into programming, however I keep running into a `'return' outside function` error. I am aware that this is due to indentation issues, however I have been messing with the indentation for hours with no success

As I have just started experimenting with Selenium, this script is supposed to scrape the product price of an item on Amazon continuously, hence the `while True:` condition.

Then I tried to implement some exception handling by using the `except NoSuchElementException`, so the error is printed, otherwise the script would continue to return the information I need.

Code:

```
def get_product_info(driver):
    title_id = "productTitle"
    price_id = "priceblock_ourprice"
    image_url_id = "landingImage" 

while True:
    try:

        product_title = driver.find_element_by_id(title_id).text
        product_price = driver.find_element_by_id(price_id).text[2:]
        product_image_url = driver.find_element_by_id(image_url_id).get_attribute('src')

    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('Not Available')
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)

    else:
        return 
        {
            "title": product_title,
            "price": product_price,
            "img_url": product_image_url
        }
```

Comment: The `while True` and everything under it needs to be indented by four spaces if that's all intended to be a part of the function.

Comment: Now it just prints "Not Available" infinitely, how do I make it print Not available only once and return the product information if available?